# After a divorce, does the man still have to pay Haq Maher which was a Saudi Arabia trip?

Tags: talaq, mehr

If a man divorces his wife due to infidelity. And the haq maher agreed at the time of nikkah was a trip to Saudi Arabia. Does this need to still be upheld, what would be the equivalent to have the haq maher paid.

Answer (score 0):

The wife is entitled to her haq mehr as soon as the marriage contract is signed, and it is independent of divorce. Only if the divorce occurs before any sexual intercourse, half of the mehr should be paid.If the trip is enjoyable, the man should take  her on the trip or send her. If the trip cost is recorded as mehr, it can only be paid.

[Reference](https://www.al-islam.org/ask/topics/13999/questions-about-Mahr)